# javascript prototype property with no value set yet

Tags: javascript, oop

So basically I made a dummy master Object and then added a property to all its children via the prototype property. But of course it is an empty property. While doing the conditional check using the `in` operator to see if the object had the new property it turned out to be false and output, "Nothing there." Is this because the property doesn't have a value yet?

```
function Master(age, sex, location)
{
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.location = location;
}

var me = new Master(99, "Male", "Texas, USA");

Master.prototype.username;


if("username" in me)
{
    document.write("The prototype put the property there.");
}
else
{
    document.write("Nothing there.<br />");
}
```

Comment: In Chrome I see: `Nothing there`.  If I explicitly set `Master.prototype.username = undefined` I see `The prototype…`.  What browser are you running in?  In general, adding a property to a prototype is like adding a class variable - in this example all instances of `Master` will have the same value for `username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is **no property** yet. Just attempting to read the property does not spring it into existence. `Master.prototype.username;` is the same as saying `window.foo` - it just evaluates to `undefined`, but nothing else happens. If you want to set a value for it, try:

```
Master.prototype.username = undefined;
```

or better

```
Master.prototype.username = null;
```

The difference between `null` and `undefined` is pretty much that it is easier to check if a property is `null`; and if you pass some functions the value `undefined` as an argument, they think you did not pass any value at all.